# what does --port option do in a k8s pod

Tags: kubernetes

if I create a pod imperatively like this, what does the --port option do?

`kubectl run mypod --image=nginx --port 9090`

nginx application by default is going to listen on port 80. Why do we need this option?
The documentation says

> --port='': The port that this container exposes.

If it is exposed using `kubectl expose pod mypod --port 9090`, it is going to create service on port 9090 and target port 9090. But in the above case it neither creates a service

Answer (score 3):

`...nginx application by default is going to listen on port 80. Why do we need this option?`

The use of `--port 80` means the same if you write in spec:

```
...
containers:
- name: ...
  image: nginx
  ports:
  - containerPort: 80
...
```

It doesn't do any port mapping but inform that this container will expose port 80.

`...in the above case it neither creates a service`

You can add `--expose` to `kubectl run` which will create a service, in this case is the same if you write in spec:

```
kind: Service
...
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
...
```

Note you can **only** specify one port with `--port`, even if you write multiple `--port`, only the last one will take effect.

Answer (score 1):

When port option is already given to pod,

1. expose can be run without --port option and it will use what is defined for the pod
2. expose can be run with --port option and it will override the option given in the pod

When --port option is neither defined in the pod nor in expose it will be an error.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#ports

Comment: I think this shouldn't be an answer to that post but instead, you could've just added this note as a comment for additional information.